# Unpivot table with values in different rows

Tags: sql-server

I have a table where one of the columns let's say `col_val` contains once a description of an action and once a time value for that action.
E.G.

```
MachineXYZ, SerialNo
MachineXYZ, Action1 Desc
MachineXYZ, Action1 Time
MachineXYZ, Action2 Desc
MachineXYZ, Action2 Time
...
```

I need to unpivot this so to get:

```
MachineXYZ, Action1 Desc, Action1 Time
MachineXYZ, Action2 Desc, Action2 Time

...
```

Any suggestions?  I never used unpivot before.
Thank you very much for suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

This may not be exactly what you are looking for since I am not using unpivot for the answer. Given your example of an asset table and a transaction table I decided to use rank to select just the first two transactions for each machine. You could change the rank order by to desc if you wanted the last two actions.

```
DECLARE @machine TABLE
      (
          machineName  VARCHAR(50)
        , serialNumber VARCHAR(50)
      );

INSERT INTO @machine
     (
         machineName
       , serialNumber
     )
VALUES
     ('ABC', '1234')
   , ('XYZ', '4321')
   , ('YYZ', '2112');

DECLARE @machineAction TABLE
      (
          machineName   VARCHAR(50)
        , machineAction VARCHAR(50)
        , actionTime    TIME
      );

INSERT INTO @machineAction
     (
         machineName
       , machineAction
       , actionTime
     )
VALUES
     ('XYZ', 'Installed', '22:50:07')
   , ('XYZ', 'Replaced', '23:44:22')
   , ('ABC', 'Installed', '05:11:01')
   , ('YYZ', 'Installed', '02:50:07')
   , ('YYZ', 'Replaced', '06:44:22')
   , ('YYZ', 'Removed', '10:33:12');

WITH cte_actionRank
    AS (
           SELECT ma.machineName
                , ma.machineAction
                , ma.actionTime
                , seq = RANK() OVER (PARTITION BY ma.machineName ORDER BY ma.actionTime)
             FROM @machineAction AS ma
       )
SELECT machine     = m.machineName
     , m.serialNumber
     , action1     = a1.machineAction
     , action1Time = a1.actionTime
     , action2     = a2.machineAction
     , action2Time = a2.actionTime
  FROM @machine                      AS m
      LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_actionRank AS a1
          ON m.machineName = a1.machineName
             AND a1.seq = 1
      LEFT OUTER JOIN cte_actionRank AS a2
          ON a1.machineName = a2.machineName
             AND a2.seq = 2;
```